# Table Thead be full size of browser with centered tbody

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to achieve something that looks like this:

[image]

So the thead is 100% of the width of the screen but the tbody is centered.

I have the following markup:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I also made a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3KYWL/

Edit: Sorry, I should have mentioned that since I'm using the datatables jQuery plugin I have to:

1. have it just be one table
2. have the same number of columns in the thead and tbody

Comment: Seems like you would just need an extra column on the left and right.

Comment: @j08691, Sorry I forgot to mention that I need to have the columns in the thead and tbody be the same amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at the following jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/3KYWL/13/

HTML:

```
<table class="centered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table { 
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.centered{
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}

thead th, tbody td {
    padding:15px;
    text-align:left;
}

thead {
    background:green;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

thead tr {
     width: 75%;
     display: table;
     margin: 0 auto;
}

tbody {
    width: 75%;
    display: table;
    background:aqua;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't line the columns up? Also, I should have mentioned in the question that I need to have it be one table, because I use the datatables jQuery plugin on the table before rendering it.

Comment: @the_ All right. This should work. http://jsfiddle.net/3KYWL/12/ I just added the `display: table` property to some of your elements. :)

Comment: Thanks for helping, but the thead isn't full width anymore?

Comment: @the_ Oops. Just changed the width on the `centered` class back to 100% (you originally had it at 700px). It works now. http://jsfiddle.net/3KYWL/13/